# List of Arrays to single Dictionary using LINQ

Tags: arrays, linq, list, dictionary

I have a problem which i can solve with two explicit loops. I want to solve it, however, with the powers of linq.

```
class Job
{
     public string[] Mapping { get; }
}

static Dictionary<string, int> GatherMappings(List<Job> jobs)
{
     Dictionary<string, int> mappings = new Dictionary<string, int>();

     foreach(var job in jobs)
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < job.Mapping.Length; ++i)
         {
              mappings.Add(job.Mapping[i], i);
         }
     }

     return mappings;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have that `string[] Mapping` at all? Don't you get an exception due to duplicate keys because the inner loop always starts again at index=0? However, i'm missing details to show you another way.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not in charge of that part of the project and in my opinion it is a bad design. There are no duplicate keys because all strings are unique.

Comment: @TimSchmelter There are no duplicated keys because the key is the string value not the index of the loop.

Comment: @user3652672 Assuming that you are looking for simplicity in your code I think that you wont get it, because the solution using Linq is pretty ugly in my opinion. You should balance simplicity and legibility when doing this type of refactoring. Just saying.

Comment: @agarwaen I agree with your argument and my main goal was to learn which i have.

Comment: @user3652672 Great!!! I'm here for the same reason (+1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return jobs.SelectMany(j => j.Mapping.Select((m, i) => new { m, i })).ToDictionary(j => j.m, j => j.i);
```

Comment: in this case, where the strings are all unique it works. thank you very much.